# Implementation Details of Sitecore Search ITagRepository

Tags: sitecore

We are trying to create custom tag repository in Sitecore instance. In order to create the repository, we would need to implement ITagRepository interface and its methods.

But we couldn't find any online references detailing the implementation details and how to go about it.

Any pointers or references are welcomed and deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the new Sitecore content search, but as a general Sitecore tip; if you inspect the Sitecore DLLs with [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) you should be able to get an idea of their inner workings.

Things I was able to find:

1. The interface `Sitecore.Buckets.Interfaces.ITagRepository` can be found in **Sitecore.Buckets.dll**
2. An implementation of this interface exists in `Sitecore.Buckets.Search.Tags.SitecoreHostedTagRepository` (also in Sitecore.Buckets.dll).  This could be a good place to start when creating your own implementation.
3. There is some documentation here: [Developer's Guide to Item Buckets and Search](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/developer%27s_guide_to_item_buckets_and%20search_sc7-a4.pdf). (I think you will need an account on sdn.sitecore.net to view this).